# Ran chown -R user /var and most things are broken

Tags: macos, permission

As the title says I ran `sudo chown -R user /var` and now most things on my machine are broken. I've fixed some permissions manually (in /var/folders) by checking against another machine but it still freezes after 10-30 minutes of use.

I tried to reinstall OS X but the installation hangs at a certain point and doesn't look like continuing. "Repair Permissions" runs but does not fix the problem. "Verify Disk" completes but "Repair Disk" just fails halfway through.

There are messages in the Console that look concerning but it's hard to tell which caused the freeze and harder to correlate the error message with a program or a permissions issue.

I don't have a backup or I would restore from it.

Curious about your thoughts,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Try run this in terminal:

```
diskutil repairPermissions /
```

[About DiskUtil Repair Permissions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: Is that any different from running it in the Disk Utility app? Things are still broken, I've ran repair permissions several times.

Comment: No, this is the same thing.

Comment: I think the fastest way would be to install completely new system. Try 1) make new partition on you drive 2) install new os x on it 2) migrate with migrate assistant data from old partition (only user data) 3) check if everething is allright 4) drop old partition and extend new to all disk  p.s. ofcourse  you should make a backup